# why does redis-cli get the value of an object set by programm always nil

Tags: redis

i have used spring-data-redis and set the template as follow:

```
@Bean
public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
    RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<String, Object>();
    template.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
    //template.setDefaultSerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
    return template;
}



@Autowired
private RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate;
private ValueOperations<String, Object> valueOps;
public static final String CATEGORY="QUOTE"; 

public void save(String key, String value) {

    valueOps.set(key, value);
    logger.info("redis get key={}, value={}", key, get(key));
}
```

when i run the code ,it can display the value as the String,

```
Aug 02, 2017 5:00:52 下午 com.web.service.QuoteRepo save
INFO: redis get key=QUOTE:932:324371:rem, value=4
```

when i go to redis client

```
$ ./redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379>get QUOTE:932:324371:rem
(nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Watch out this code line :

```
private ValueOperations<String, Object> valueOps;
```

You should inject the template as a ValueOperations. You forgot something like this:

```
@resource(name="redisTemplate")
private ValueOperations<String, Object> valueOps;
```

Refer to this for more: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/1.8.6.RELEASE/reference/html/ 
Section5.5 is helpful for you.